# mongoexport only object value

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I have a really simple mongodb with only one property that i am saving, email.
I am successful at exporting that collection into a csv.
This is what it looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn9Vp.jpg

What i would love to be able to do is only export that data this is in the 'email' property.
That way I do not have to do cleanup everything i want to use this .csv in mailchimp etc...

This is my mongoexport command

`mongoexport -d myDatabase -c emails -o export.csv`

Am i able to do this in mongoexport or do i need to do some custom view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `mongoexport` in following way:

```
mongoexport -d myDatabase -c emails -f email --csv -o export.csv
```

where `email` is name of field that you want to export.

You need to give full path while exporting.

Comment: Great.  Thank you, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**MongoExport**

Sample Document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5694e6c5ad7b7e6a6953fb9e"),
"address" : {
    "location" : "Dharmapuri",
    "city"     : "Chennai"
},
"author" : {
    "name" : "Ponpal Johnson"
},
"book" : "origin of species"

}
```

MongoExport syntax

```
mongoexport --host <hostname> --db <Database Name> --collection <collection Name> --csv --fields fieldname1,fieldname2 --out fileName.csv
```

Example : **Export in CSV Format**

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db library --collection book --csv --fields address.location,author.name,book --out author.csv
```

Example : **Export in JSON Format**

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db library --collection book --fields address.location,author.name,book --out author.json
```